# grouping data in arrays (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to make a nice ordered way of grouping objects in an array. Now I've tried the following, but it gives me an error.

Any tips?

```
#body: mass, [x,y], [vx,vy], [ax, ay]
bodies = np.array([[1E3, [0,0], [0,0], [0.0]],\
          [1, [0,200], [31.6,0], [0,0]]])
```

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a complex dtype:

```
bodies = np.array([(1E3, [0,0], [0,0], [0.0]), 
                   (1, [0,200], [31.6,0], [0,0])], 
                   dtype=[('mass',float), ('xy','2float'), 
                          ('vxy','2float'), ('axy','2float')])
```

and access the "columns" with

```
In [63]: bodies['mass']
Out[63]: array([ 1000.,     1.])

In [64]: bodies['xy']
Out[64]: 
array([[   0.,    0.],
       [   0.,  200.]])
```

etc.,
but this will not make your life any easier.

---

> I am making an n-body simulator

Calculating distances between objects will be a common operation in an `n`-body simulator. You might want to use [scipy.spatial.distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) `pdist` or `cdist` for that. Notice that these functions expect `X` to be NumPy ndarrays of simple, homogenous dtype. So if you were to use an array of complex dtype, you'd always have to slice it first before you could use any of these functions.

Therefore, it probably would be simpler to just store arrays of simple, homogeneous dtype from the beginning and avoid the array of complex dtype.

I suggest making multiple 1-dimensional arrays:

```
mass = np.array(...)
x = np.array(...)
y = np.array(...)
```

or maybe use some 2D-arrays of simple, homogenous dtype:

```
pos = np.array([(x0, y0), (x1, y1), ...], dtype='float')
```

All your equations will be more readable this way too.
Instead of accessing the 2D position array with `bodies['xy']` you would simply write `pos`. That's one less set of brackets your eyes will have to parse.

Comment: Yeah, making separate 1D arrays will probably be easier.

Comment: Made it like this, not the prettyest of things but works well :P

Comment: mass = np.array([1E3, 1, 20, 10])
Rbod = np.array([[0,0],[0,200],[0.,100], [0,300]])
Vbod = np.array([[0,0],[31.6,0],[31.6,0], [31.6,0]])
Abod = np.array([[0,0],[0,0],[0,0], [0,0]])

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dtype=object`, and then store anything you want—floats, tuples, lists, arrays. But really, that's not a good idea; you pretty much lose all the benefits of numpy.

And, because it's a bad idea, numpy doesn't make it easy for you. If you construct an array out of a list, it assumes any sub-lists are dimensions of the array, and if it can't make any sense of things that way, it gives you this error.

Why not just store the bodies as flat rows of numbers? You already have to interpret the rows as bodies at a higher level, and really, how is `x, y = bodies[1][1]` any better than `x, y = bodies[1][1:3]`?

If you really want to, you could create an array with one more dimension, but… why?

You also might want to consider using pandas instead of raw numpy, or using a database instead of using numpy in the first place, or just keeping each `body` as a Python object (whether sticking them in a numpy array or not), or something else entirely. Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to be sure what fits your needs. But it's pretty unlikely that what you're trying to do is the right thing to do.

Comment: I am making an n-body simulator with as ultimate goal to simulate the solar system. And I need to sort the objects in a easy to access/sort way.

Comment: How do you expect grouping them like this to make sorting easier? If you keep them separate, you can sort on the `x` column or the `y` column; how would you even get started with sorting if there were a single `xy` column whose values were composite?

Comment: More importantly, presumably the reason you're using numpy in the first place is to allow you to simply and efficiently perform operations on the whole set at once. If `x` and `y` are separate columns, you can operate on either one easily; if there's an `xy` column, each value of which is a 2x1 array… you can't do anything useful with that at all.

Comment: I work with the little 2x1 vectors directly. So [a,b] is "one" number.

Comment: @Coolcrab: But it's a "number" you can't do any numpy arithmetic on, so what does that get you? Also, again, how is it any harder or less readable to access those 2x1 vectors as `bodies[1][1:3]` instead of `bodies[1][1]`? The huge advantage of doing it the former way is that you can access the whole pair of columns as a 2xN vector as `bodies[:][1:3]`, while there's no way you can do that  your way.